# How to round a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

I have a numpy array, something like below:

```
data = np.array([  1.60130719e-01,   9.93827160e-01,   3.63108206e-04])
```

and I want to round each element to two decimal places.

How can I do so?

Comment: `np.round(data,2)`?

Comment: Your example works just fine. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: `np.round` is equivalent to `np.around` and both work for entire arrays.

Comment: What exactly do you want the rounded output to be?

Comment: I think he ment to say that how to reduce the numbers after decimal `1.60130719e-01` to `1.60`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Numpy provides two identical methods to do this. Either use

```
np.round(data, 2)
```

or

```
np.around(data, 2)
```

as they are equivalent.

See [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html#numpy.ndarray.round) for more information.

---

Examples:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0.015, 0.235, 0.112])
>>> np.round(a, 2)
array([0.02, 0.24, 0.11])
>>> np.around(a, 2)
array([0.02, 0.24, 0.11])
>>> np.round(a, 1)
array([0. , 0.2, 0.1])
```

Comment: array was not np array, after importing like np.array its working

Comment: Available also as method [`round()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html#numpy.ndarray.round): `a.round(decimals=2)`

Answer (score 10):

It is worth noting that the accepted answer will round small floats down to zero as demonstrated below:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> arr = np.asarray([2.92290007e+00, -1.57376965e-03, 4.82011728e-08, 1.92896977e-12])
>>> print(arr)
[ 2.92290007e+00 -1.57376965e-03  4.82011728e-08  1.92896977e-12]
>>> np.round(arr, 2)
array([ 2.92, -0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ])
```

You can use `set_printoptions` and a custom formatter to fix this and get a more numpy-esque printout with fewer decimal places:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': "{0:0.2e}".format})
>>> print(arr)
[2.92e+00 -1.57e-03 4.82e-08 1.93e-12]
```

This way, you get the full versatility of `format` and maintain the precision of numpy's datatypes.

Also note that this only affects printing, not the actual precision of the stored values used for computation.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the output to be

```
array([1.6e-01, 9.9e-01, 3.6e-04])
```

the problem is not really a missing feature of NumPy but rather that this sort of rounding is not a standard thing to do. You can make your own rounding function which achieves this like so:

```
def my_round(value, N):
    exponent = np.ceil(np.log10(value))
    return 10**exponent*np.round(value*10**(-exponent), N)
```

For a general solution handling `0` and negative values as well, you can do something like this:

```
def my_round(value, N):
    value = np.asarray(value).copy()
    zero_mask = (value == 0)
    value[zero_mask] = 1.0
    sign_mask = (value < 0)
    value[sign_mask] *= -1
    exponent = np.ceil(np.log10(value))
    result = 10**exponent*np.round(value*10**(-exponent), N)
    result[sign_mask] *= -1
    result[zero_mask] = 0.0
    return result
```

Comment: This was more or less what I wanted. Using `np.around` instead of `round` will make it work for multidimensional arrays as well.