# How to shorten a float result in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

Below is a (1,3) array that represents the world coordinates of detected car's Centroid:

```
World_Point=[[3.27996023 0.29204794 1.        ]]
```

How can I turn the float numbers into the format shown below?

```
World_Point=[[3.27 0.29 1]]
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994426/how-to-round-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @JenilDave. Thanks man. Apparently, my question is duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `round(number, ndigits)` function.

Answer (score 2):

do this for two decimal points :

```
result = (round(Wprld_Point, 2))
```

or as for list

```
for x in World_Point:



  (round(x, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
World_Point=[[3.27996023, 0.29204794, 1.0  ]]

def myround(numbers):
    return [round(x,2) for x in numbers]


World_Point = list(map(myround, World_Point))

print(World_Point)
```